# ADD FRIEND Button / Link

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am creating a social site using PHP and HTML. i want to add "**ADD FRIEND**" button or link on my site. I wonder how can i do that. means whenever user searches for some name, then related search get displayed sequentially.

What i want is add friend button in front of every user that listed by search.. is there any way i can do that?

**so if user click on that button then user id and friend id get inserted into friend table?**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is too open-ended and shows you haven't tried or experimented with anything yourself. It's like asking "I'm building a car, I want it to have wheels. What should I do?".

Comment: You should try writing an add friend button, and then if the code you wrote doesn't work, ask that as a question. Questions asked on Stack Overflow should have first attempted to be solved by the asker.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i am searching for the answer which can help me a little .. i just want some hint about the same ,,,,

Comment: it is not like i am having user id in session and friend id in textbox .. i am listing the name of all users .. and cant provide link in front of every name so that if user click in that link .. the data get inserted into the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've done this, first of all set a session variable and store current logged in user id in that like this

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = //loggedin user id
```

now I am not aware what kind of database design are you using, or what because you've not specified or provided any code from your side but simple way you can do this is make a simple submit button encapsulate it within a form tags, and use post method

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_friend'])) {
$current_user = $_SESSION['user_id']; //This will fetch user id of the person who is logged in and for this you need to have a user id in your session for the user who logs in

$friendid = $_POST['friend_id']; //This will assign friend id to variable $friendid

//Now execute the insert statement
if(mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO addfriendtable(user_id, friend_id) VALUES('$current_user','$friendid')")) {
echo 'success';
} else {
echo 'Error Occured';
}
}

$fetch_records = mysqli_fetch_array($connect, "SELECT name, userid FROM table");
while ($show_users = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_records)) {
//loop all search results
//place this code in front of all results
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $show_users['user_id']; ?>" name="friend_id">
<input type="submit" name="add_friend" value="Add Friend" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help .. this is what i am looking for .. but cant find in net.. Thanks once again

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh SQL injection

Comment: you can tick this answer as correct if it solves your question so that future users like you who are searching for something like this can refer

Comment: @darvids0n I guess he is a newbee, no code provided nothing, I can't sanitize it without knowing what actual code he is using, this was just the blueprint I posted

Comment: @Mr.Alien I would real_escape_string the params at least, after that it's situation-specific.

Comment: yes i am new on this stack overflow ... next time i will be more specific for my Question :)

Comment: I guess `mysqli_real_escape_string`  has no use over here as the data is passing with post, just numbers I assume as a user id, so there's no question of **quotes**, and moreover, I would use `is_numeric` or `is_int` or something to be sure that the user id what am going to post is an integer, but that too depends on his design, if he only uses number's as user id's

Comment: Mr.Alien for now i am creating separate table for every user that sign ups ,,, means if user name sumit4548 sign ups then table named Sumit4548friends will created .. or should i create a single table for user and his friend ,, your suggestions

Comment: oh yes, why to create separate tables? what if users reach upto 100000, this is not a right way to do it, you can accomplish this with just a single table